# How does First.Cells(i,1) function?

Tags: vba, excel, spreadsheet

I am trying to modify a command that I originally found here. http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/790-excel-insert-sheet-names-in-cells.html  Originally, the command was attached to an ActiveX Control button.  It made a new sheet.  Then put all the names of the sheets in the workbook in the first column, new row per name.

That code is:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Set NewSheet = Sheets.Add(Type:=xlWorksheet)
  For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
  NewSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = Sheets(i).Name
  Next i
End Sub
```

I modified it to stop creating a new sheet and just put the list starting in A2 on the sheet where the button is located.

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
  Range("A2").Select
  Dim First As Worksheet
  Set First = Workbooks.Item(1).Sheets.Item(1)
  For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
  First.Cells(i, 1).Value = Sheets(i).Name
  Next i
End Sub
```

Now, on each of the non-summary sheets, I have data in rows.  In column A, I have placed a 1 next to each row with data in it.  So, cell A1, sums these and tells me how many rows of data I have.  Currently, they range from 1 to 5.

I would like to check the A1 cell and if the value is greater than 1, paste the sheet name on the summary tab equal to the number of rows of data in the data tab.

I have tried changing For i = 1, to For i = x and defining x as the A1 cell, but I'm very new at VBA and this keeps running me into problems.  What I'd really like to know, is how does this line work?

```
First.Cells(i,1).Value=Sheets(i).Name
```

I can't find a reference to First.Cells anywhere on the site.    I think this would give me a better idea of how to go about making the changes I need.

Thank you for any and all help!

Answer (score 1):

In the code, `First` is a worksheet object that is set with this line:

```
Set First = Workbooks.Item(1).Sheets.Item(1)
```

This code sets the variable `First` to the first worksheet in the first workbook in Excel.

After the worksheet is set, `First.Cells(i,1)` references that worksheet and the cell at the `i` Row, column 1 (column A).  The `.Value` property is being set to the sheet name of `Sheets(i)`.

Stated another way, that line is setting the cell value of row i, column A to be the name of the worksheet that is in position i.  So if you create a new workbook with default values (that is, sheet names of `Sheet1`, `Sheet2`, and `Sheet3`) the code will set `First` to `Sheet1` and then print the name of all worksheets in that workbook on column A on `Sheet1`.

If you need to do a check of the value in A1 on each worksheet, you can access the value of a cell or range by using `Sheets(i).Range("A1").Value` which will return the value in cell A1 of the sheet at position `i`.

You can test for values like so:

```
'Ignore the summary sheet
If Sheets(i).Name <> "Summary" Then
    If Sheets(i).Range("A1").Value > 1 Then
        'Set the sheet name and record count
        Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, 1).Value = Sheets(i).Name
        Sheets("Summary").Calles(i, 2).Value = Sheets(i).Range("A1").Value
End If
```

Assuming your summary sheet name is `Summary` this code will pass over it and then will place the sheet name and row count in column `i` on the `Summary` sheet in columns A and B, respectively.  I should note that if one sheet does not have a value > 1 then it will skip a row on your summary sheet.  There are ways around this.  For now I would start with the above and if you have any questions I can clarify.  I would put this code immediately after the `First.Cells(i, 1).Value = Sheets(i).Name` line.

Answer (score 0):

The statement `Dim First As Worksheet` defines `First` as a `WorkSheet` variable.

The statement `Set First = Workbooks.Item(1).Sheets.Item(1)` assigns the variable `First` to point to the the first worksheet in the first workbook that is in Excel's list of open workbooks.

Note that the name `First` is coincidental, and has nothing to do with the fact that it's pointing at the first workbook opened or first sheet in that workbook. The variable name could easily have been `Foo`, and it would have still pointed there.

The fact that it's pointing to the first workbook is determined by the **1** in `Workbooks.Item(1)`, and the first worksheet by the **1** in `.Sheets.Item(1)`. You've hard-coded that in there, so that's what it's pointing to.

Your line in question:

```
First.Cells(i,1).Value=Sheets(i).Name
```

takes the `.Name` of `Sheet(i)` and puts it into `Cell(i,1)` of the worksheet `First`.

A helpful note:  `Item` is the default property of both the `Worksheet` and `workbook` objects, so you could have written your statement a little more cleanly, like this:

```
Set First = Workbooks(1).worksheets(1)
```